# SQL STATEMENT keyword

Tags: sql

While going through the SQL CTEs I came across this: [CODE Project CTE](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265371/Common-Table-Expressions-CTE-in-SQL-SERVER)

The code is:

```
WITH ShowMessage(STATEMENT, LENGTH)
AS
(
SELECT STATEMENT = CAST('I Like ' AS VARCHAR(300)), LEN('I Like ')
UNION ALL
SELECT
      CAST(STATEMENT + 'CodeProject! ' AS VARCHAR(300))
      , LEN(STATEMENT) FROM ShowMessage
WHERE LENGTH < 300
)
SELECT STATEMENT, LENGTH FROM ShowMessage
```

or even a small modified one:

```
WITH ShowMessage(STATEMENT, LENGTH)
AS
(
SELECT STATEMENT = 1, LEN('I Like ')
UNION ALL
SELECT
      STATEMENT + 1
      , LEN(STATEMENT) FROM ShowMessage
WHERE STATEMENT < 50
)
SELECT STATEMENT, LENGTH FROM ShowMessage
```

The above code works perfect, when I try the code as:

```
with k (TT,LL)
as
(
select TT= 1, 1
union all
select TT+1,1
WHERE TT < 50
)
select TT,LL from k
```

My code does not work, error is that COLUMN TT does not exists. After a careful observation found that the STATEMENT is a keyword (UI showed in blue color); then I started searching online for the meaning of this keyword but could not find one (Google always throws only SELECT statement - not the STATEMENT)

Could you please explain what is this STATEMENT keyword and where/how to use it. Or please point me to the right source to learn it.

Comment: `TT = 1` is invalid standard SQL (unless there is a column `TT` - in that case it's just a boolean expression). Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some product specific SQL used there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query :

```
;WITH k (TT,LL)
as
(
  SELECT 1, 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TT+1,1
  FROM k  --- you miss that table 
  WHERE TT < 50
)
SELECT TT,LL FROM k
```

Comment: Got it, but K is not filled unless the  code in the bracket is executed, so how does it work?

Comment: At the time first SELECT 1, 1 statement executed table K created automatically.

Comment: So in CTE, each recurssion fills the variable? also, I did not change the value of  TT any where, so how come it gets increment continously, could you please explain or point to a source for learning on it? I am pretty much confused on how it gets updated.

Comment: Refer below sites for more details : ( 1 ) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx.  ( 2 ) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx.

Comment: That helped...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add table i.e k.

```
with k (TT,LL)
as
(
select  TT=1 , 1
union all
select TT+1,1 From K
WHERE TT < 50
)
select TT,LL from k
```

Comment: Got it, but K is not filled unless the  code in the bracket is executed, so how does it work?